# SELECT INTO paired with BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, etl

Is there a way to combine `SELECT INTO` with `BULK INSERT` such that you don't need to define the table being bulk inserted into?

pseudo code would look like

```
BULK INSERT INTO #temp
FROM 'C:\file.txt'
```

Comment: "Trial and error" is a nice way of learning that

Answer (score 0):

Table must exist.

```
 BULK INSERT #temp
    FROM 'C:\file.txt'
```

You can use openrowset instead.